# How to display center image bigger in listview vertically with scroll option in android?

Tags: android-listview, android-overscoll

right now i am going on with listview along scrolling. I have successfully created listview with scroll in vertical view, right now what i need is center item in listview should be greater than remainning one's in view. If we scroll listview items, item which gets in center should be greater than remainning ones. I tried for getting sample or any linked answers but i can't get it still, can you guys help me with this.

Comment: You probably want a [wheel](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/142).

Comment: ya something like that, to show only center image bigger than remainning ones.

Comment: You can possibly modify one of those controls. There are open source ones.

Comment: can you send any open source ones that suits me or any link.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/